# How to find tight upper bound?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to find a tight upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i)\left(\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\right)$ where the maximum value of function is $a$ and minimum is $b$, and both of them are positive, also, $s_i, t>0$. I am able to find the bound on $\left(\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\right)$ (see below), but how do I incorporate the information of $f(s_i)$ in $g(t)$?

\begin{align*}
&\frac{(1 - \exp(-s_it))(1 + s_it)}{s_it} \leq g(t)  \\
&\Rightarrow  \frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} \leq g(t)  \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\\
&\Rightarrow  \frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it} \leq (g(t) - 1) \frac{1}{1 + s_it},  \\
\end{align*}
where $g(t)$ is given as:
\begin{align*}
g(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{(1-\exp(-vt))(1+vt)}{vt}  & \mbox{if } t \leq 1.7933/s_{\max} \\
  \frac{(1-\exp(-wt))(1+wt)}{wt} & \mbox{if } t \geq 1.7933/s_{\min} \\
  1.2985 & \mbox{if } 1.7933/s_{\max} < t < 1.7933/s_{\min} \\
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

Edit 1: I am not sure if $g(t)$ is tight enough or not, if the difference between maximum value and minimum value of $s$ is very large, then it is quite loose. Should I use some other function? Also, at $t \rightarrow 0$ and $t \rightarrow \infty$, the function should go to 0.

Comment: Do you mean that $s\in [s_{\min}, s_{\max}]$ and $b \le f(s) \le a$ for all $s \in  [s_{\min}, s_{\max}]$? Is $b\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: What type of upper bounds do you want? Do you want $\left(\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\right) \le g(t)$? Any properties of such $g(t)$ do you need?

Comment: @RiverLi Something stricter than $g(t)$, which I provided in the question. The problem with the above function is when $s_\max / s_\min$ is too large; it is quite loose. I am not looking for something in particular, just that even when $s_\max / s_\min$ is large, the bound should be good.

Comment: You first write $\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i)\left(\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\right))$ 
(so we can find an upper bound for $\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}$).
Now, you write $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(s_i)}{1+s_it}\left(\frac{(1 - \exp(-s_it))(1+s_i t)}{s_it} - 1\right)$
and find an upper bound for $\frac{(1 - \exp(-s_it))(1+s_i t)}{s_it}$. Is the latter better? I want to ask the question again, what type of upper bounds do you want finally? Does it look like $\sum_i f(s_i) g(t)$ or ......?

Comment: @RiverLi I am looking for something of the form $\sum_i h(s_i,t)$ where $h(s_i,t)$ contains $f(s_i)$ and 'can' contain $g(t)$ or some other function that is stricter than what I have written above. I am not sure if $g(t)$ is the right choice. That is why I mentioned that you are free to choose another function which can beat $g(t)$. I used $g(t)$ as a starting point.

Comment: It is more clear now.

Comment: One more question. You have the form of $\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i)\left(\frac{1 - \exp(-s_it)}{s_it} - \frac{1}{1 + s_it}\right)$. If you get an upper bound of the form of $\sum_i h(s_i,t)$ (for example, according to your $g(t)$), it looks not simpler than the starting form. What benefit do you obtain (if there is no simple form tight upper bound)?

Comment: The $g(t)$ function does not rely on $s_i$, it is only the function of $s_\max$ and $s_\min$. The final function can be a simple form or can be a complex function of $s_\max$ and $s_\min$.

Comment: OK. Thanks for explanation.